# How can I set the text of a DIV that's specified with a jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var oLink = {
        $modal: '',
        $message: ''
    }

oLink.$message = oLink.$modal.find('.message');
```

I tried to set the text of this variable like this:

```
oLink.$message.Text("Contacting Server, please wait ... ");
```

but it gives an error message saying undefined even though the debugger says the oLink.$message is an HTMLDIVelement. The element with the class of .message is a DIV. How can I set the text inside of the DIV?

Comment: `.text()` should have a lowercase t

Comment: And you're calling `.find()` on an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. .text solved the problem. Sam

Answer (score 2):

It should be `.text()` not `.Text()`.

Also, are you sure `oLink.$message` really refers to a div?

If you do a `console.log(oLink.$message)` what do you see in your console?  (You'll need to use Firefox with the firebug plugin installed to do this).